# wallpaper is not sliding on first boot

Tags: android, android-ndk, wallpaper, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I built new ROM (4.2.2) to set my customized wallpaper as default wallpaper.It displayed fine, but at the first boot the wallpaper is not sliding (left to right, right to left).

If I rebooted my android device it is working fine. I made changes in

1. `packages/apps/Launcher2/res/values-sw720dp/wallpapers.xml`
2. `packages/apps/Launcher2/res/values/wallpapers.xml`

Do I need to make any more changes to slide the wallpaper at the first boot?
**[Note]** This is my first post, Please ask if you need extra details.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO it can be migrated to Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: Please try and properly format your questions. ALL CAPS IS NOT VERY APPRECIATED. SMR did a good job of cleaning up your question. Try and follow that style next time.